# Strange update issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a piece of code that updates person information.

```
module People
  class Update
    attr_reader :person_id, :params

    def call person_id, params
      @person_id = person_id
      @params = params

      update_person
    end

    def update_person
      @person = Person.find(person_id)
      @person.update(params)
      @person
    end
  end
end
```

params equals

```
{"first_name"=>"Blue", "last_name"=>"Panther", "email"=>"bluepanther9@gs.co.za"}
```

person_id has a value and exists in the database. Pretty simple and straight forward.

The weird thing is I get an error when everything executes through the application, but it works fine when I do it through rspec or the console manually. See error below.

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activemodel-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:249:in `block in update' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:345:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:218:in `transaction' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:342:in `with_transaction_returning_status' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:248:in `update' 
/storage/www/testing.phoenix.site.co.za/app/services/people/update.rb:14:in `update_person' 
/storage/www/testing.phoenix.site.co.za/app/services/people/update.rb:9:in `call' 
/storage/www/testing.phoenix.site.co.za/app/services/people/create_or_update_person.rb:24:in `create_or_update_person' 
/storage/www/testing.phoenix.site.co.za/app/services/people/create_or_update_person.rb:15:in `call' 
/storage/www/testing.phoenix.site.co.za/app/services/events/incoming/identify.rb:19:in `create_or_update_person' 
/storage/www/testing.phoenix.site.co.za/app/services/events/incoming/identify.rb:13:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:30:in `perform' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:94:in `block in invoke_job' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:91:in `invoke_job' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in run' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:199:in `block in run' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:198:in `run' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:275:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:275:in `reserve_and_run_one_job' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:182:in `block in work_off' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:181:in `times' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:181:in `work_off' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:146:in `block (4 levels) in start' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:145:in `block (3 levels) in start' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:144:in `block (2 levels) in start' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:143:in `loop' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:143:in `block in start' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:142:in `start' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:124:in `run' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:112:in `block in run_process' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `block in start_proc' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call_as_daemon' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:259:in `start_proc' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:296:in `start' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in start_all' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `fork' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `block in start_all' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `each' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `start_all' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:80:in `run' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `block in run_proc' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:110:in `run_process' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:91:in `block in daemonize' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:89:in `times' 
/home/getsmart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@phoenix/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:89:in `daemonize' bin/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

Note that the code is being executed from delayed job. Not sure if that will make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace with

```
@person.update(params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email))
```

You should not use `permit!` blindly, the point is to ensure people can only change what you allow.

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes No it doesn't

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes no at all, both `update` and `update_attributes` are aliases btw

Comment: see doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update

Comment: I think the `People::Update` `ActiveModel` is created in controller, so `permiting` params should be on controller level.

Comment: its debatable, I usually `permit!` in controller and always `slice` in service objects, depends how comfortable you are with ruby/rails. Recommending `permit!` could lead people to make huge mistakes

Comment: Another quick question related to this ... why did I actually get the error via delayed job, but not in my `rails console`? I can open another question, but I think it makes sense to ask here. Thanks.

Comment: because in console you use a Hash, params are a slightly different object